# Как задать выравнивание секций в ELF файле?

Tags: gcc, elf

Есть ли способ задать страничное выравнивание для секции .text ELF файла при сборке с помощью GCC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для выравнивания секций в ELF можно использовать скрипты линкера ([мануал](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html)).

Конкретно для выравнивания секции .text в тексте ld-скрипта должно быть что-то типа:

```
.text ALIGN(0x2000): { *(.text) }
```

В ld ld-скрипт передается с помощью опции -T.